# Laravel Some email cannot delivered on server

Tags: laravel, email, sendgrid

Some email cannot delivered on server, when i send test email, it work perfectly, but when i send order details email or user account details, it just can't work.

here is my code:

```
$fromData = $toData = [];
        $fromData = [
          "subject" => "User Credentials",
          "email" => "admin@gaias.co",
          "username" => "Gaias"
        ];

        $toData = [
          "subject" => "User Credentials",
          "email" => "chengwei@joycular.space",
          "username" => "ycw",
          "password" => "1233",
        ];

        // send email
        Mail::send('mail.userCredentials', $toData, function($message) use ($fromData, $toData) {
          $message->from($fromData["email"], $fromData['username']);
          $message->to($toData["email"], $toData["username"]);
          $message->subject($fromData["subject"]);
        });
```

Here is my setting in .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=XXX
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXX
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: Any errors logs?

Comment: Not returning any error, using Mail::failures() feature also return success status

Comment: Have you check the logs from your queue while sending the order email? Try run `tail -f storage/log/laravel.log` to watch the log.

Comment: hmmmm, log show nothing wrong, i got solution now, by using Mailgun